# Can't turn on addon without closing and reopening Blender

Tags: add-on

I am relatively new to coding,I tried to make an add-on consisting of multiple modules.

Once I removed the add-on and tried to install it again it gave the error

```
    ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass'RenderPanel'
```

Then blender needed to be restarted.

Does it have something to do with this statement?

```
     if __name__ == "__main__":
        register()
```

Comment: Do you have an `unregister()` method in your `__init__.py`, that properly unregisters `RenderPanel`?

Comment: i have used this command

def unregister():

    for module in modules:
        module.unregister()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Comment: take a look at this https://docs.blender.org/api/3.3/info_overview.html?highlight=unregister_class#module-registration
Also note that if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_" is only for testing, therefore not needed in the addon script.